# UIView beginAnimations fails on selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:4];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
navigation.frame = CGRectOffset(navigation.frame, 0, 430);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Code block above works fine when called manually on viewDidLoad function or with button tap. But when i try to call that block within a selector function like below, animation doesnt effect. Object jumps to position. What would cause to that?

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:)])
{
    [delegate carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:self];
}


- (void) carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation:(iCarousel *)carousel{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
    navigation.frame = CGRectOffset(navigation.frame, 0, 430);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

[icarousel github](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still don't know the real problem but

```
[self performSelector:@selector(makeAnim) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0001];
```

solved my problem.

Hope helps anyone.

Still needs a better solution.

Comment: I think you'll find that a delay of 0 probably works just as well. What the code is doing is delaying the effect until the next screen update cycle (~1/60th second) which probably prevents it from being interfered with by whatever other animations are in progress.